# Require operator double() to be explicitly called via static_cast<double>(x)

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++17, static-cast, explicit-conversion

I'd like to enable conversion of my class to a double value. This can be achieved by overloading `operator double()` but this then allows for implicit conversion, which ideally I'd like to be able to avoid.

Is there any way to add this functionality but with the requirement that conversions are made using `double y = static_cast<double>(x)` rather the implicitly being made; `double y = x`?

I'm using C++17. Thanks

Comment: By using the [*`explicit`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) keyword for your [user-defined conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)?

Comment: @user0042 (a) constructors, not "constructor functions" (b) not [since C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit)

Comment: This is one of those rare cases when C++ declaration syntax makes sense.

Comment: @VTT: what do you mean, can you explain please?

Comment: @geza I mean that to make some user-defined conversion function explicit one needs to use `explicit` keyword instead of some gibberish.

Comment: @VTT: ah, okay :)

Comment: This question uses terminology correctly. It is unfortunate that the title of the question cited as a duplicate refers to the non-existent "cast operator". It is a **conversion operator**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can mark conversion operators explicit since C++11.

```
explicit operator double() { /* ... */ }
```

This will prevent copy-initialization, *e.g.,*

```
double y = x;
return x;  // function has double return type
f(x);  // function expects double argument
```

while allowing explicit conversions such as

```
double y(x);
double y = static_cast<double>(x);
```

Comment: Thank you. It did not occur to me that the explicit keyword would effect the static_cast operator. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Use `explicit`:

```
struct X {
    explicit operator double() const { return 3.14; }
};

double y = static_cast<double>(X{}); // ok;
double z = X{}; // error
```